# Question on a finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic

I have a simple question regarding a particular form of a sum and I was hoping someone could provide some insights or guidance.

if $n\:=\:\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{g\left(n,k\right)}{f\left(g\left(n,k\right)\right)}\:$

What are the properties of $f(x,y)$, $g(x,y),$ and most importantly, $n$?
Bear in mind that in this particular sum, $x | f(x,y)$ and $x | g(x,y)$
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "what are the properties of"? Is $f$ a function of one variable or two variables? What do your statements involving "$|$" mean?